# Wait for fetch request to finish to initialize components on React Hooks & Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, shopify

I am currently trying to connect my shopify account to react using js-buy-sdk.

I can get my products calling `fetchByHandle` after buildClient in same component. However, I want to use my client returned from buildClient in many different components. Do I need to call buildClient in every component? I tried to use redux for defining global state to client in App.js but subcomponents are not waiting for the buildClient function completes and are giving `client.product.fetchByHandle is not a function`.

This is my code (ProductPage component to fetch product):

```
    const client = useSelector(state => state.client);
    useEffect(() => {    
        if(client && client.product) {
            client.product.fetchByHandle('any-handle').then(product => {
                setProduct(product);
            });
        }
    }, [client]);
```

App.js

```
  useEffect(() => {
      const client = Client.buildClient({
          domain: 'xyz.myshopify.com/',
          storefrontAccessToken: 'token'
      });
      dispatch(setClient(client));
      client.product.fetchAll().then((products) => {
          console.log(products);
          dispatch(getProducts(products));
      });  
  }, [dispatch]);
```

Comment: why don't you use Context? which will give you redux like flavour. If you don't have that much complexity in your project then go for ContextApi.

Comment: I don't think that you need to save Client initialization into React state. Just put that outside your App component and then passed it as props to ProductPage.

Comment: @ridoansaleh I am actually using like that and it is working but I am looking for an different approach on hooks and redux

Comment: @ErdemGonul .. oh i see. You can use Hooks instead to save the data you got from Backend API. Just leave the Client initialization as it was.